# How can I initialize a group of variables to FALSE in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to set all these variables to equal false in as little lines of code as possible.  Is it possible to do it all on one line?   The code below doesn't work, but that is what I am looking for, instead of doing $a = False; $b = False; etc

```
$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $e= FALSE;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$a = $b = $c = $d = $e = FALSE;
```